# File upload with angular 4 and spring framework

Tags: spring, angular, file-upload

I'm trying to get file upload works with angular 4 and spring framework,I have implemented the following code but it doesn't work.

angular component.ts

```
 upload() {
    let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
    let fileCount: number = inputEl.files.length;
    let formData = new FormData();
    if (fileCount > 0) { 
        for (let i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
            formData.append('file[]', inputEl.files.item(i));

 }

       console.log(fileCount);// print count of files correctly 

    this.http.post("/filestorage/api/upload", formData) 
                     .map(res => res.json()) 
                     .subscribe();
    }
}
```

spring controller

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
@Timed
public void upload(@RequestParam(value="file", required=false)
        MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        System.out.println(file); //get null value
  }
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-files-upload have alook

Comment: did u try renaming the value to 'file[]' because thats the field's name in the FormData Object (what excatly is the problem/does not work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed MultipartFile to MultipartHttpServletRequest and made required changes,now it works fine.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
@Time
public void upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
    MultipartFile multipart = request.getFile(itr.next());
    java.io.File convFile = new java.io.File( multipart.getOriginalFilename());
        convFile.createNewFile(); 
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile); 
        fos.write(multipart.getBytes());
        fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your upload function, try adding the headers to your request, ex:

```
upload() {
   let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
   let fileCount: number = inputEl.files.length;
   let formData = new FormData();
   if (fileCount > 0) { 
       for (let i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
           formData.append('file[]', inputEl.files.item(i));
       }
       console.log(fileCount);// print count of files correctly 

       let headers = new Headers();// import { Headers,BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
       headers.append('enctype','multipart/form-data');
       headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
       let options = new BaseRequestOptions();
       options.headers = headers;   

       this.http.post("/filestorage/api/upload", formData , options) 
                    .map(res => res.json()) 
                    .subscribe();
   }
}
```

Tested with Angular 4.